# TranslateTransform offsets element a bit too much after multiple transforms in Windows 8 store application

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-store-apps, translate-animation

I have a draggable element in a StackPanel in a Windows 8 store app. My goal is simple: drag the item somewhere on the screen and immediately after the user stops dragging it the element should return to its original starting position.

I have the following code which is meant to accomplish this task:

```
private void grdCover_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Grid coverControl = sender as Grid;
        double xOffset = -e.Cumulative.Translation.X;
        double yOffset = -e.Cumulative.Translation.Y;
        if (coverControl.RenderTransform is TranslateTransform)
        {
            TranslateTransform existingTransform = coverControl.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform;
            existingTransform.X += xOffset;
            existingTransform.Y += yOffset;
        }
        else
        {
            TranslateTransform transform = new TranslateTransform();
            transform.X = xOffset;
            transform.Y = yOffset;
            coverControl.RenderTransform = transform;
        }
    }
```

The code sort of works. The screen looks like this upon application start:

[image: Initial screen showing the well aligned H and U elements]

The top element, which looks like a H is well aligned with the bottom element which looks like a U. When I first drag the H element it jumps back to its well aligned position, or at least any misalignment is so little that it's hardly perceivable to the naked eye. As I keep dragging and releasing the H element it gets more and more misaligned like this:

[image: The H element is losing its original position]

After 15-20 dragging moves the H element gets completely misplaced:

[image: The H element is completely misplaced]

The problem might be due to some rounding error of the double values in the Point objects when they are translated into pixels, but that's only a wild guess. Also, on a high resolution device, such as my PC it takes more moves for the misalignment to become visible than on a lower resolution one, such as the Windows Simulator in Visual Studio.

Some other code that may be related to this issue:

I perform the dragging operation with the following code:

```
private void Grid_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TranslateTransform translateTransform = (sender as Grid).RenderTransform as TranslateTransform;
        translateTransform.X += e.Delta.Translation.X;
        translateTransform.Y += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
    }
```

I also have the following event handler in place to stop the element from moving too much on the screen after the user is done dragging the element:

```
private void grdCover_ManipulationInertiaStarting(object sender, ManipulationInertiaStartingRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.TranslationBehavior.DesiredDeceleration = 10000000000000000;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

In case you're wondering I wanted to set the desired deceleration to Double.Max to block any further "sliding" movement on the screen but I got an exception saying it was out of bounds. So instead I chose this arbitrary large value.

I have no extra margins or padding on the layout root or the element to be moved or its container.

Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks, Andras

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got it to work. The problem was that there was a slight mismatch between the Point coordinates in the following code bits:

```
TranslateTransform translateTransform = (sender as Grid).RenderTransform as TranslateTransform;
translateTransform.X += e.Delta.Translation.X;
translateTransform.Y += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
```

and

```
double xOffset = -e.Cumulative.Translation.X;
double yOffset = -e.Cumulative.Translation.Y;
```

The solution was to retrieve the value of

```
e.Delta.Translation.X
```

and

```
e.Delta.Translation.Y
```

and assign their values to the variables xOffset and yOffset. Retrieving the values of

```
e.Cumulative.Translation.X
```

and

```
e.Cumulative.Translation.Y
```

gave slightly different coordinates so the element kept jumping back to the wrong location.